# How to throw an exception on an CompletableFuture.get() call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, completable-future

Is there a way to have mockito throw an exception on the `CompletableFuture.get()` call and not just the asynchronous method?

For example, given the following (incorrect) test case:

```java
@Test
public void whenRunnerThrows_thenReturn5xx() throws Exception {
    when(service.runAsync(any(),any())).thenThrow(new Exception(""));

    mvc.perform(post("/test")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content("{\"name\":\"test\"}"))
            .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError());
}
```

When `service.runAsync()` is called during testing, an exception is thrown, which makes sense. But when the (Spring Boot) application is run, then the same exception will only be thrown as a an `ExecutionException` cause on the returned `CompletableFuture::get`.

What is the correct way to write a test like this one so that the exception is thrown at the same time in unit testing as it is when running the application?

Comment: Why don't you create a `CompletableFuture` that's been completed exceptionally and `thenReturn` it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Sotirios pointed out, you can create a `CompletableFuture` and have it complete with the exception. Here's the code for reference to others:

```java
@Test
public void whenRunnerThrows_thenReturn5xx() throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> badFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    badFuture.completeExceptionally(new Exception(""));
    when(service.runAsync(any(),any())).thenReturn(badFuture);

    mvc.perform(post("/test")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content("{\"name\":\"test\"}"))
            .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError());
}
```

Comment: Starting with Java 9, you can use `CompletableFuture.failedFuture​(new Exception(""))` to achieve the same.